# undefined method `get?' for 302:Integer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, turbolinks, ruby-2.5

I like to upgrade the ruby version from `2.4.2` to `2.5.0` in my rails application.

All specs/tests fail where I use turbolinks. 
Is there a known issue with turbolinks and ruby `2.5.0`?

Here is the output on the terminal.

```
Failure/Error: expect(request).to redirect_to company_salesmen_path(salesman.company)

NoMethodError:
    undefined method `get?' for 302:Integer
  # /Users/dennish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/turbolinks-5.1.0/lib/turbolinks/assertions.rb:37:in `turbolinks_request?'
  # /Users/dennish/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.0/gems/turbolinks-5.1.0/lib/turbolinks/assertions.rb:6:in `assert_redirected_to'
  # ./spec/requests/salesmen_spec.rb:206:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

This is the spec:

```
describe 'DELETE /salesman/:id' do
  subject(:request) do
    delete salesman_path(salesman), headers: auth_headers
  end

  let!(:salesman) { create :salesman }

  it 'destroys salesman' do
    expect { request }.to change { Salesman.count }.by(-1)
  end

  it 'redirects to index' do
    expect(request).to redirect_to company_salesmen_path(salesman.company)
  end
end
```

Comment: 1. You should paste the error message in form of text, not as an image. 
2. You should probably show how your `salesmen_spec.rb` file looks like.

Comment: Already did. Maybe you remove your downvote

Comment: If you disable turbolinks, what happens?

Comment: an issue has been filled: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-rails/issues/38

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **root cause** of this error is:

```rb
subject(:request)
```

By assigning `:request` we are [overwriting rails internals](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-rails/issues/38#issuecomment-391086418) - hence it breaks and the tests fail wierdly.

#### The Solution

Just go with the default *(no name)*

```rb
subject { delete salesman_path(salesman) }
```

Or you can [rename the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53321936/2235594):

```rb
subject(:http_request) { delete salesman_path(salesman) }
```

Both solutions will make the tests succeed.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue it seems to be a compatibility issue with Turbolinks 5.1 and Rails 5.0.x. Downgrading to Turbolinks 5.0.1 solved it for me.

Comment: Looks like, this is the only way

Answer (score 3):

By renaming the `request` to `http_request` is solving this.